# Web scraping an Ajax webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the list items (state names: [list of states](https://www.britannica.com/topic/list-of-cities-and-towns-in-the-United-States-2023068#toc326668)); the states are visible on the web page as a list but are dynamic . Can I scrape them in BeautifulSoup? Is it doable? Some hints, please. New to web scraping! Open for other tool

```
<div class="md-nav-item cite hidden-xs" data-popover=".citation-popover" data-popover-url="/ajax/topic/2023068/cite?citeUrl=https://www.britannica.com/topic/list-of-cities-and-towns-in-the-United-States-2023068">
  <em class="material-icons" data-icon="bookmark">
  </em>
  <div class="hidden-xs">
   Cite
  </div>
  <div class="citation-popover md-popover text-left">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking - BeautifulSoup is a parsing library; it does not pull the webpage for you. You may pull the HTML file first, and then use BeautifulSoup to parse the content, sure.

Comment: The webpage/html I parsed into `soup` does not have the list. Instead has an hidden-xs div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

States weren't dynamic, try with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https: ...url here'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


for i in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'md-crosslink'}):
    print i.text
```

The above code uses [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)'s *attrs* field to specify that we are interested in the `a` tag with the `class="md-crosslink "` items, and most specifically about the text they contain.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Glad to help !!!